# converting excel date into mm/dd/yyyy format

Tags: java, date, apache-poi

I am reading from an excel sheet using poi jar where in there is a date column.If i print out the value of the data cloumn :

```
cell.getDateCellValue()
```

It gives me value like 3124.0

So i tried with this code to convert to the mm/dd/yyyy format:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/YYYY");
String  s =  sdf.format(cell.getDateCellValue());
System.out.println(s);
```

But for reading a date 06/30/2001 i got this value as output:

06/181/2001

Comment: If excel sheet is in your control, please change excel content to text format(Right Click on the content -> Format Cells --> Text). And java code will see same content that was there in Excel.

Comment: That "value" is the number of days since January, 00th 1900.

Comment: I suggest you to look at the [SimpleDateFormat class reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) So you can easily edit your code

Comment: Your cell value for the date should be `37072.0`. Also, please read up on the valid Java date format characters.

Comment: Did you try using [DataFormatter from Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Date Format String is wrong. Should be like following

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Read the Java doc for [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: These classes are now legacy, supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 3):

First check your date format

```
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/YYYY");
```

it should be

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

and also check the POI API For more info to deal with dates in excel,there are better ways to handle the dates.

Refer [HSSFDateUtil](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFDateUtil.html)

check HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted() , getExcelDate ,getJavaDate

**getJavaDate**

**public static java.util.Date getJavaDate(double date)**

Given an Excel date with using 1900 date windowing, and converts it to a java.util.Date.

NOTE: If the default TimeZone in Java uses Daylight Saving Time then the conversion back to an Excel date may not give the same value, that is the comparison excelDate == getExcelDate(getJavaDate(excelDate,false)) is not always true. For example if default timezone is Europe/Copenhagen, on 2004-03-28 the minute after 01:59 CET is 03:00 CEST, if the excel date represents a time between 02:00 and 03:00 then it is converted to past 03:00 summer time
Parameters:

date - The Excel date.
Returns:
Java representation of the date, or null if date is not a valid Excel date

See Also:
TimeZone

also refer [Reading date values from excel cell using POI HSSF API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861877/reading-date-values-from-excel-cell-using-poi-hssf-api)

Comment: This is incorrect.  It should NOT be `mm/dd/yyyy` because `mm` means minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the JavaDoc for `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`:

`D` is for Day in year

`Y` is for Week in year.

You propably want to use the lowercase variants for `d` Day in Month and `y` Year

Answer (score 2):

You want to write `"MM/dd/yyyy"` as your date format.  Capital `DD` means day of year, which for 30 June is 181.

I strongly recommend reading the [JavaDoc for the `SimpleDateFormat` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

Date is actually stored as number in a cell.

```
CellType cellType = cell.getCellType();
if (cellType == CellType.NUMERIC) {
     double numberValue = cell.getNumericCellValue();
 
     if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
         Date javaDate= DateUtil.getJavaDate(numberValue);
         //use DateFormat or as it is
         myObj.setValueFromCell(javaDate);
      } else {
         // Use BigDecimal to avoid  Scientific numbers like 1.2345678E9
         String stringCellValue =  BigDecimal.valueOf(numberValue).toPlainString();
         myObj.setValue(stringCellValue);
    }
}
```